# Obtaining the probability based on Normal Distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Obtain
$P(1.65<\overline{X}\leq 4.35,0.12<S^2\leq 55.26)$
If $X_{i}$ follows $N(3,12)$ and $i=1,2,3$.

**My approach**

Since, $\overline{X}$ and $S^2$ are independent, the given probability can be factored into two individual probabilities. After adjusting terms and making standard Normal and chi square, we have:

$(2\Phi_{0.675}-1)P(0.02<\chi_{2}\leq 9.21)$

Which gives me $(0.9)(0.98)=0.882$.

But none of the options seems to be true. I am not able to identify where the problem is?

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions before using them, thanks!

Comment: What is $S^2$ here?

Comment: @BrianTung $S^2$ is the sample variance and that is $\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{3}(X_{i}-\overline{X})^2$.

Comment: $2\Phi(0.675)-1=0,500324235056446$.